# Is it necessary to remove ground on all layers when using isolated DIO

Tags: opto-isolator, layout, routing, ground-plane, digital-isolator

So, I am using uptocouplers and digital isolators for a project connected to a microcontroller GPIO. I removed the ground (ground plane cutouts) under the load side of the components, is it necessary to do this on all 4 layers or just on the toplayer where the components are located?
I do have vias carrying the load-side signals near the components, that's why I cut away all ground. Is this correct?
The PCB is meant as a control hub for an AGV with a nominal working voltage of 48VDC (battery supplied, 55V charger supplied, during deceleration or braking up to 100V). The loads controlled are various contactors, detectors and a motor brake input.

Comment: You haven't justified that it's necessary at all. Who knows what "the load side" means other than you? Who knows what circuit you are talking about or what your requirements are?

Comment: Hi, Andy, you are right. The "load side" are various industrial detectors, an isolated CANbus, various relays and a motor-break input.

Comment: Don't put amendments into comments, add the detail to your question and furnish the other things I mentioned too.

Comment: The requirements Andy asked you about include things like what not only what voltages this isolation should protect against, but what the type of system that's coming from, for instance mains has 1500V spikes on it, and why, as medical or explosive atmospheres require better isolation than lab.

Comment: @Neil_UK Okay, done!

Comment: @AlexEr Not done! Why do you want isolation, what are you protecting against? Are you protecting for electrical safety, or RF signal isolation so you need low capacitive coupling, or simple breaking the ground path to avoid DC continuity? The specification is often the hardest part of a project to get right, it takes a lot of experience to figure out what's really needed. Once that's stated clearly, it becomes obvious what sort of gaps are needed where.

Comment: Are you using the same ground for all components?